# Unbinding event handler that was bound with .on()

Tags: event-handling, jquery

I'm trying to unbind some event handlers that were bound with `.on()`, but nothing seems to work:

**HTML:**

```
<div class='parent'>
    <a id='test-1' class='test'>Test 1</a>
    <a id='test-2' class='test'>Test 2</a>  
    <a id='test-3' class='test'>Test 3</a>
</div>
<hr>
<a class='unbind'>Unbind Test 1</a>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.parent').on('click', 'a.test', function(e){
    alert('click');
});

$('a.unbind').click(function(e){
    $('a#test-1').unbind('click');
    $('a#test-1').off('click');
});
```

**Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/g9ucd/5/

---

**CLARIFICATION:** Per the example, I want to know if it's possible to unbind *specific* elements that had previously been bound with `.on()`, rather than just reversing the all the bindings with `.off()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [jQuery API on method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) documentation states that the event is actually placed on the elemented it is called from, the filter selector you apply is used to then determine which elements the event is valid on. So the short answer is NO you can't unbind the even from an element that is designated by the filter selector.

However, have you considered working around this by constraining your selector further?

You could remove the test class from the a element and then by that scenario it would no longer meet the filter selector's criteria and thus be untied to the event.

Just a thought.

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ermagana/g9ucd/6/) and below is the snipped that i changed.

```
$('a.unbind').click(function(e){
    $('a#test-1').removeClass('test');
});
```

Comment: Also see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18593652/165673) for a variation on this..

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
var clickie = function(e){
    alert('click');
}

$('.parent').on('click', 'a.test', clickie);

$('a.unbind').click(function(e){
    $('.parent').off('click', 'a.test', clickie);
});
```

Thing is, you never set a handler on `a#test-1` - you set it on `.parent`. You can't remove what you didn't set. If you need to remove a handler from `a#test-1`, you must not use the live functionality: `$('.parent a.test').on('click', clickie)` will bind your function onto the elements themselves, so you can `off` them individually.

Comment: @Yarin: I said so if you read the explanation later. You did *not* bind to anything except `.parent`, so you can only unbind from `.parent`. If you want to unbind from individual elements, then you have to bind to individual elements.

Comment: I disagree with "_If you need to remove a handler from a#test-1, you must not use the live functionality_". For at least two options on how to achieve the same effect, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18583215/548696).

Comment: @Tadeck: You did not remove a handler from `a#test-1`. You made `a#test-1` not match the handler set on `.parent`; there is only one handler, it is on `.parent`, and it is still there. By "remove a handler", I meant "use `off()`". I don't think anyone would agree that "remove a handler" is in the purview of `removeClass` method, or that `if` statement "removes" anything at all except an execution path.

Comment: That is technicality and I specifically said "_how to achieve the same effect_", not "_how to do that_". I have given a solution that works exactly as OP wanted, except it is not about "unbinding" handlers. Unbinding handlers is silly, since when you bind it to single container, it cannot be unbind from its children. But you can make it stop working on some children that were previously working. This is exactly what OP wanted, regardless of the fact it has nothing to do with unbinding. Hope that is clearer now.

Comment: @Tadeck: I know perfectly well what you're saying, and I think it's a good approach. I completely agree with your second sentence. And you'd be very correct to call me out on a technicality if *I* nitpicked at *you*. But in your first sentence, you went on record to disagree with a demonstrably true statement. Now, that can happen to anybody; but defending incorrect statements rather than admitting a bug and fixing it is not something I would have expected of a programmer. "Yeah, that's a fence-post error in that for-loop, but I don't need to fix it, you know what I meant, right?"

Comment: Ok, I think I know what you mean. I think you defend "_If you need to remove a handler from a#test-1, you must not use the live functionality_", and I actually second that. My point was that you can achieve similar effect by basically using different technique, not involving unbinding. This is kind of like the jQuery's event delegation (when you use `.on()` with `selector` argument) - it does something more before calling the handler (it checks, if target matches that selector). Sorry for misunderstanding. I could have formulated my comment differently. Your answer is okay, upvoting.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
$('a.test').on('click', function(e){
    alert('click');
});

$('a.unbind').click(function(e){
    $('a#test-1').unbind('click');
    $('a#test-1').off('click');
});
```

Comment: @Farax- thanks, this is indeed the (easy) solution. (Amadan was just a few minutes faster--)

Comment: @Yarin: Unfortunately binding handlers this way is obviously not using delegation, so if you have dynamic content (eg. links loaded with AJAX), you will either need to attach separate handler to each just after loading them into DOM, or resort to something else.

Comment: @Tadeck- You're right- I'm looking for a delegated solution, this would not work

Answer (score 1):

You need to add more logic to it:

```js
$('.parent').on('click', 'a.test', function(e){
    // retrieve switch value:
    var disable_calls = $(this).data('disable-calls') || false;
    if (!disable_calls){
        // your logic here...
        alert('click!');
    };
});

$('a.unbind').click(function(e){
    // disable call by turning the switch:
    $('a#test-1').data('disable-calls', true);
});
```

Event handlers are attached to the outer element (`.parent`) and jQuery gives you a shortcut for actually checking `event.target` (you do that by supplying selector within `.on()` call). To alter that logic, you need to add your own special handling, or eg. make sure that selector is no longer matched:

```js
$('.parent').on('click', 'a.test.calls-enabled', function(e){
    alert('click!');
});

$('a.unbind').click(function(e){
    // disable call by turning the switch:
    $('a#test-1').removeClass('calls-enabled');
});
```

Comment: a good approach I think you could have also just removed the test class from the element and thereby removed the need to add additional info to the markup.

Comment: @ermagana: Yes, this is exactly the same idea: make the selector no longer match the target.

Comment: @Tadeck- thanks for this- You and ermagana both gave good work arounds.

Answer (score 1):

A variation on [@ermagana's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18583212/165673) and [@Tadeck's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18583215/165673) answers is simply to use the `:not` selector on the initial delegated binding. That way, you can "unbind" certain elements by explicitly disabling them with an extra class.

(In this case, I'll use the `.disable` class, which would give extra benefit of disabling them visually if you were using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/) etc..)

```
$('.parent').on('click', 'a.test:not(.disabled)', function(e){
    alert('click');
});

$('a.unbind').click(function(e){
    $('a#test-1').addClass('disabled');
});
```